# Setting While Loop to Loop Maximum of 3 Times

Tags: python, function, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to get my `while` loop to loop a maximum of 3 times before the program quits while also informing the user of their remaining attempts.

```
def main():
    valid = 0
    while (valid == 0):
        valid = checkValid ()
    print ('and the program continues on with User_Input2()...')
    #User_Input2()
```

And here is the code for `checkValid()`

```
def checkValid():
    if ((iVelocity < 20) or (iVelocity > 800) or (iTrajectory < 5) or (iTrajectory > 80)):
        result = 0
    else:
        result = 1
    return result
```

And what the main program looks like:

```
iVelocity = float(input('Please enter an initial velocity between 20 to 800 m/s: ' ))
iTrajectory = float(input('Please enter an initial trajectory angle between 5 to 80 degrees: '))

main()
```

I'm not sure where to add code in either function to get it to loop (or if I need to create something along the lines of `def counter():`), inform the user of their remaining attempts, and how to quit the program if all 3 attempts have been used.

Comment: Put before your loop a line that says `attempts = 0`; change `while (valid == 0)` to `while attempts < 3 and valid == 0`, or better `while attempts < 3 and not valid`; right after the `valid = ...` line, put a line that says `if not valid: print("{} attempts left".format(3 - attempts))`; then after that `if` block, say `attempts += 1`.

Comment: Tried it and I get the input statements followed by:

3 attempts left
2 attempts left
1 attempts left

Then it moves on to User_Input2 regardless.

Comment: After your `while` loop, say `if not valid: return False` or whatever.  You might want to raise an error, return something that indicates no success, just something to mean no-can-do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a `for` loop with `break` command:

```
for i in range(3):
    valid =checkValid()
    if(valid==1):
        break
```

Comment: Uhh, not sure why this is downvoted, seems more natural than adding a counter. One note is that I'd replace `i` with `_`.

Comment: I don't why it was downvoted, seems like a good idea, though I tried it and it continues with `User_Input2 ()` even if invalid numbers are entered (ie a `0` is returned to `checkValid ()`)

Comment: I see this cleaner as well, and it was my first idea. But I decided to keep closer to the original code.

Comment: After tinkering around with the code, I ended up taking your advice and using a for `for` loop instead. Cleaned up the code quite a bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would include the input request in `main`. On my understanding, you want something like this:

```
def main():
    valid = 0
    count = 1
    while (valid == 0):
        iVelocity = float(input('Please enter an initial velocity between 20 to 800 m/s: ' ))
        iTrajectory = float(input('Please enter an initial trajectory angle between 5 to 80 degrees: '))
        valid = checkValid(iVelocity, iTrajectory)
        if count == 3:
            break
    print ('and the program continues on with User_Input2()...')
    #User_Input2()

def checkValid(iVelocity, iTrajectory):
    if ((iVelocity < 20) or (iVelocity > 800) or (iTrajectory < 5) or (iTrajectory > 80)):
        result = 0
    else:
        result = 1
    return result

main()
```

Comment: This was the closest to what I was looking for. Thank you.